# Can I create scratch org with some languages activated in Translation Workbench?

Tags: scratch-org, translation-workbench, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm trying to create scratch org where the languages in Translation Workbench would be marked as 'Active' by default. For example I would like to create scratch org with Japanese activated by default. I know that first of all Translation Workbench has to be enabled and I have done that using this:

```
"languageSettings": {
        "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
},
```

and that works. But I cannot find a way to activate Japanese when creating scratch org. Is that even possible, or do I have to do that manually? (I have the ja.translation-meta.xml)

I want it to looks like this by default:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you able the list of supported languages upon scratch org creation? Or did you add them manually?
When I create a scratch org with languageSettings on the definition file, as you mention above, I have an empty list of supported languages.

Comment: SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could contribute to SFSE in ways that you gain reputation so that you can comment under someone else's question (you only need 50 rep); or you could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you could link to this question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, if you have a [Translations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm) Metadata file (like `translations/fr.translation-meta.xml` for instance), pushing it to the scratch org will create the language as active.

If the language has been deactivated previously (like in a sandbox), it won't be reactivated though, but that shouldn't be an issue for you during scratch org creation.

However there is also a [Translation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_translation.htm) object that can be queried/updated to change that status via the `IsActive` field.